# Why does asigning DIFFERENT values of an iterated list as keys to a dictionary only returns a single key (the last value of the list)?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary with keys as numbers of a list and value "None". However, the output is a dictionary with a single key. I thought it would return the three numbers as keys because they are **different keys** and, therefore, the key-values are not being re-assigned.

Here's my code:

```
def dicc_test():
    lista = [3,4,5]

    for n in lista:
        dicc = {}
        dicc[n] = None
    return dicc

print(dicc_test())
```

This prints the following:

```
{5: None}
```

I don't understand why it does'nt print something like this:

```
{3: None, 4: None, 5: None}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a new dictionary for every loop iteration. Create it once before the loop:

```
def dicc_test():
    lista = [3,4,5]

    dicc = {}
    for n in lista:
        dicc[n] = None
    return dicc

print(dicc_test())
```